# custom list field not showing on envelope with Docusign API

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I am having a problem with adding custom list fields to an envelope through the API. The problem actually comes in the form of the list field not appearing on the envelope, but when I make a "GET" request to retrieve all the custom fields on the envelope, it shows that the custom field is there. Below is the function to add a custom list field, followed by the xml string response from DocuSign.

```
    Private Sub btnTEST_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTEST.Click
    Dim envelopeId As String = txtEnvelopeID.Text
    Dim url As String = baseUrl & "/envelopes/" & envelopeId & "/custom_fields"
    Dim xmlString As String =
        "<customFields>" & _
            "<listCustomFields>" & _
                "<listCustomField>" & _
                    "<name>Test Custom List</name>" & _
                    "<value>Donatello</value>" & _
                    "<show>true</show>" & _
                    "<required>true</required>" & _
                    "<listItems>" & Chr(34) & "Donatello" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "Michaelangelo" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "Raphael" & ", " & Chr(34) & "Leonardo" & Chr(34) & "</listItems>" & _
                "</listCustomField>" & _
            "</listCustomFields>" & _
        "</customFields>"
    basicRequestResponse("POST", url, xmlString)
End Sub
```

DocuSign's XML Response when retrieving the custom fields on the envelope.

```
 <customFields xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.or/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <listCustomFields>
          <listCustomField>
              <fieldId>22047120</fieldId> 
              <name>Test List</name> 
              <required>true</required> 
              <show>true</show> 
              <value>Test 1</value> 
              <listItems xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <a:string /> 
              </listItems>
          </listCustomField>
          <listCustomField>
              <fieldId>22049808</fieldId> 
              <name>Test Custom List</name> 
              <required>true</required> 
              <show>true</show> 
              <value>Donatello</value> 
              <listItems xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <a:string /> 
              </listItems>
          </listCustomField>
    </listCustomFields>
    <textCustomFields>
        <textCustomField>
            <fieldId>21991323</fieldId> 
            <name>Leet Test</name> 
            <required>true</required> 
            <show>true</show> 
            <value>1337</value> 
        </textCustomField>
  </textCustomFields>
```

I realize this may be a bug within DocuSign's API but wanted to put it out here and see if there is a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by the fact that you're setting **<listItems>** incorrectly in the "Create Custom Envelope Field" request -- hence DocuSign is creating the custom (list) envelope field, but ignoring the list item values you specified in the request.

Here's an example of a valid XML request structure for adding a (List) Custom Envelope Field:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/custom_fields

<customFields>
    <listCustomFields>
        <listCustomField>
          <name>TestCustomList</name>
          <value>Donatello</value>
          <show>true</show>
          <required>true</required>
          <listItems>
            <string>Donatello</string>
            <string>Michaelangelo</string>
            <string>Raphael</string>
            <string>Leonardo</string>
          </listItems>
      </listCustomField>
  </listCustomFields>
</customFields>
```

Notice that the content within the **<listItems>** element is a series of **<string>** elements -- each one representing a single list value.

After submitting the request above, I can execute a "Get Custom Envelope Fields" request (`GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/custom_fields`) and see that the response does indeed contain all of the list values that I specified in my earlier "Create Envelope Custom Field" request:

```
<customFields xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <listCustomFields>
        <listCustomField>
            <fieldId>22062595</fieldId>
            <name>TestCustomList</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <show>true</show>
            <value>Donatello</value>
            <listItems 
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                <a:string>Donatello</a:string>
                <a:string>Michaelangelo</a:string>
                <a:string>Raphael</a:string>
                <a:string>Leonardo</a:string>
            </listItems>
        </listCustomField>
    </listCustomFields>
</customFields>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This did give me the result I needed. Also, I will be submitting this to DocuSign to update their documentation. Currently their REST API guide says that list items should be "entered with quotations, seperated by commas."

Comment: Good idea to follow up with DocuSign regaring updating the documentation.  Keep in mind that if you were using JSON format for your request, then specifying a list of string values "with quotations, separated by commas" would be the correct way to do things -- it's just when using XML format that you need to use the <string> element to denote a string value (as described above).